# Adding script includes with an apex:component?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex

I'm looking to call my scripts through an [apex:component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_creating.htm). So instead of having 3 includes on my page, I want

```
<c:scripts />
```

and the 'scripts' component will contain the following.

```
<apex:component >       
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js')}"/> 
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js') }" /> 
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/anotherScript.js') }" />        
</apex:component>
```

But if I only want one of these scripts, can I pass a argument into the component call? Something like the following...

```
    <c:scripts
      myScript = true />
```

And then the component...

```
<apex:component >       
 Boolean myScript = <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js')}"/> 
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js') }" /> 
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/anotherScript.js') }" />        
</apex:component>
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer :)

```
<apex:component>

    <apex:attribute name="includejQuery" type="Boolean" required="false" default="false" description="True to include jQuery" />

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!includejQuery}">
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js')}"/> 
    </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js') }" /> 
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jQuery/js/anotherScript.js') }" />

</apex:component>
```

Then in my page:

```
<apex:page>
    ...
    <c:Scripts includejQuery="true" />
    ...
</apex:page>
```